# Почему VK API использует GET запросы и всегда возвращает Status Code = 200?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.
Читаю статьи про REST API и везде пишут, что для каждой операции в базе данных (CRUD) используются свои методы (POST, PUT, DELETE, GET), но VK API почему-то использует везде GET запросы (есть исключения в паре методов, где используется POST). И почему он отдает всегда Status Code = 200 (исключения - явные ошибки, например, когда отправляешь много запросов). Например, когда вызываем метод получения списка друзей и указываем не правильный токен, то получаем всё равно Status Code = 200, но в теле ответа - ошибка.[image: тело ответа]

Почему API VK всё таки использует такую позицию в использовании запросов и ответов?

Comment: Может, лучше у них и спросить?

Comment: У них - где? В тех. поддержке? Я не думаю, что они дадут ответ.

Answer (score 0):

**REST** - это рекомендации, свод правил, которые стандартизируют API.

Конечно, придерживаться стандарта считается хорошим тоном, но это совсем не обязательно и разработчики могут выбирать свои варианты реализации.